# what is the way when add new row in table to make script connect with element in new row not only at first row?

Tags: javascript

what is the way when add new row in table to make script connect with element in new row not only at first row? the script connect only with element "textbox" in the first row only

```
 function GetSelectedvalues (el) {
            var select = document.getElementsByClassName ('js-example-basic-multiple')[0];
            var result = "";
            var options = select && select.options;
            var opt;
            for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
                opt = options[i];
                var isSelected = select.options[i].selected;
                isSelected = (isSelected)? opt.value : "0";
                result +=    isSelected  ;
            }

            document.getElementById ('textbox').value=result;

        }

//add row
function addmaintable() {

    $('#datatablereqstsched').append(
        '<tbody>' +
        '<tr class="parent" id="parent">' +

// here text box
        '<td width="60%"><div class="input-group"> <label class="ckbox mg-t-10" title="Daily" ><input type="checkbox" id="chk1"  onclick="check(\'chk1\')" ><span calss="mg-t-0">Daily</span>  </label><div class="input-group-prepend" style="width:80%"><select class="js-example-basic-multiple col-md-4 form-control" name="states[]" multiple="multiple"style="width: 100%" onchange="GetSelectedvalues(event);" > <option value="1">MON</option> <option value="2">TUE</option> <option value="3">WED</option> <option value="4">THU</option><option value="5">FRI</option><option value="6">SAT</option><option value="7">SUN</option> </select></div><input type="text" class="form-control txtv" value="" placeholder="0000000" id="textbox" disabled></div> </td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>');

        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();

    }
 function check(chk) {
            var checkb = document.getElementById(chk);
            if (checkb.checked == true) {
                document.getElementById('textbox').value = "1234567";
                $(".js-example-basic-multiple").prop("disabled", true);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('textbox').value = "0000000";
                $(".js-example-basic-multiple").prop("disabled", false);
                $(".js-example-basic-multiple").val(null).trigger('change');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add more details and relevant code. There is no row, or anything that adds a row here. Just a way to display a select data into a #textbox element.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte i add details now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly targetting the first select each time you call the `GetSelectedvalues` function:

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName ('js-example-basic-multiple')[0];
```

I think you should rather leverage the event argument to get the current changing select:

```
const tBody = '<tbody>'
+    '<tr class="parent" id="parent">'
+        '<td width="60%">'
+            '<div class="input-group">'
+                '<label class="ckbox mg-t-10" title="Daily">'
+                    '<input type="checkbox" id="chk1"  onclick="check(\chk1\)" >'
+                    '<span calss="mg-t-0">Daily</span>'
+                '</label>'
+                '<div class="input-group-prepend" style="width:80%">'
+                    '<select class="js-example-basic-multiple col-md-4 form-control" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%" onchange="GetSelectedvalues(event);">'
+                        '<option value="1">MON</option>'
+                        '<option value="2">TUE</option>'
+                        '<option value="3">WED</option>'
+                        '<option value="4">THU</option>'
+                        '<option value="5">FRI</option>'
+                        '<option value="6">SAT</option>'
+                        '<option value="7">SUN</option>'
+                    '</select>'
+                '</div>'
+                '<input type="text" class="form-control txtv" value="" placeholder="0000000" id="textbox" disabled>'
+            '</div>'
+        '</td>'
+    '</tr>'
+'</tbody>'

function GetSelectedvalues(event) {
    // Here you are selecting only the first select with the class "js-example-basic-multiple"
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('js-example-basic-multiple')[0];
    // You are better off selecting the current changing select using the argument event
    select = event.target;
    var result = "";
    var options = select && select.options;
    var opt;
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        opt = options[i];
        var isSelected = select.options[i].selected;
        isSelected = (isSelected) ? opt.value : "0";
        result += isSelected;
    }
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = result;
}

//add row
function addmaintable() {
    $('#datatablereqstsched').append(tBody);
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
}
```

**Edit**
Now you need a way to know which textbox to update, based on currently changing select. And the same thing for all other inputs, like the checkbox at the top.
One way to do that could be this:

```js
const tBodyTemplate = '<tbody>'
+    '<tr class="parent" id="parent">'
+        '<td width="60%">'
+            '<div class="input-group">'
+                '<label class="ckbox mg-t-10" title="Daily">'
+                    '<input type="checkbox" id="chk"  onclick="check(chk)" >'
+                    '<span calss="mg-t-0">Daily</span>'
+                '</label>'
+                '<div class="input-group-prepend" style="width:80%">'
+                    '<select data-target="textbox" class="js-example-basic-multiple col-md-4 form-control" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%" onchange="GetSelectedvalues(event);">'
+                        '<option value="1">MON</option>'
+                        '<option value="2">TUE</option>'
+                        '<option value="3">WED</option>'
+                        '<option value="4">THU</option>'
+                        '<option value="5">FRI</option>'
+                        '<option value="6">SAT</option>'
+                        '<option value="7">SUN</option>'
+                    '</select>'
+                '</div>'
+                '<input type="text" class="form-control txtv" value="" placeholder="0000000" id="textbox" disabled>'
+            '</div>'
+        '</td>'
+    '</tr>'
+'</tbody>'

function GetSelectedvalues(event) {
    // Here you are selecting only the first select with the class "js-example-basic-multiple"
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('js-example-basic-multiple')[0];
    // You are better off selecting the current changing select using the argument event
    select = event.target;
    var textboxId = select.dataset.target;
    var result = "";
    var options = select && select.options;
    var opt;
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        opt = options[i];
        var isSelected = select.options[i].selected;
        isSelected = (isSelected) ? opt.value : "0";
        result += isSelected;
    }
    document.getElementById(textboxId).value = result;
}
let rowCount = 0;
//add row
function addmaintable() {
   rowCount++;
   var tBody = tBodyTemplate
     .replace(/textbox/g, 'textbox' + rowCount)
     .replace(/chk/g, 'chk' + rowCount);
   $('#datatablereqstsched').append(tBody);
}
function check(v) {
  console.log(v);
}

$('#add-row').click(addmaintable);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatablereqstsched"></table>
<button id="add-row">Add one row</button>
```

Comment: result appears only on first row  here

Comment: i think i should make another way here "document.getElementById('textbox').value = result;" so i want to appear result on correct row

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added an example on how to do that.

Comment: thank you it is working very well . can you explain this statement "tBodyTemplate.replace(/textbox/g, 'textbox' + rowCount); "
and what letter "/g" here?

Comment: It will replace all occurrences of `textbox` inside the `tBodyTemplate` string with a specific string for the current iteration,e.g. `textbox1`, `textbox2` ... It would be proably better to have something less generic than `textbox` as a placeholder, but it was just meant of an example.

Comment: i put it function check above now it stopped working when i applied this example

Comment: `/textbox/g` is a regular expression to find what substring to replace. The `g` at the end makes it look for all occurrences of the substring, not just the first one.

Comment: I fixed the checkbox in the above code snippet @jack

Comment: thank you .. but about check box i added  code above in question code box  function check(chk) it is not working it is not disable select2 and appear numbers 1234567 in textbox and else...